# Getstore to Buffer, not using temporary files

Tags: perl, file-handling

I've started Perl recently and mixed quite a bit of things to get what I want.

My script gets the content of a webpage, writes it to a file.

Then I open a filehandler, plug the file report.html in (sorry i'm not english, i don't know how to say it better) and parse it.
I write every line i encounter to a new file, except lines containing a specific color.

It works, but I'd like to try another way which doesn't require me to create a "report.html" temporary file.

Furthermore, I'd like to print my result directly in a file, I don't want to have to use a system redirection '>'. That'd mean my script has to be called by another .sh script, and I don't want that.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use LWP::Simple;

my $report = "report.html";

getstore('http://test/report.php', 'report.html') or d\
ie 'Unable to get page\n';

open my $fh2, "<$report" or die("could not open report file : $!\n");

while (<$fh2>) 
{
 print if (!(/<td style="background-color:#71B53A;"/ .. //));
}

close($fh2);
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

If you have got the html content into a variable, you can use a `open` call on this variable. Like:

```
my $var = "your html content\ncomes here\nstored into this variable";
open my $fh, '<', \$var;

# .. just do the things you like to $fh
```

You can try `get` function in `LWP::Simple` Module ;)

To your sencond question, use open like `open $fh, '<', $filepath`. you can use `perldoc -f open` to see more info.